# Item.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi everyone I am making a route to get the items that are created by the logged-in user but when I use the .filter function I get an error. Not sure why I am getting this error. I have made other apps before doing the same thing and never got an error

> Item.filter is not a function

The my-items route

```
const requireAuth = require("../middleware/requireAuth");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Item = mongoose.model("Item");

router.get("/my-items", requireAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const items = Item.filter((item) => item.userId === req.user.userId);
    res.send(items);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Item Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  phone: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    ref: "User",
  },
  email: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    ref: "User",
  },
  seller: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    ref: "User",
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  detail: {
    type: String,
    requiredL: true,
  },
  condition: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const items = await Item.find(({userId:req.user.userId}).lean();
```

it should return exact items from db that you want you can use more query if you need.

Comment: awesome thank you not sure why I didn't think of it

Answer (score 0):

`Item` is a model but not the documents in the database, you need to do a query first in order to get the items.

```
router.get("/my-items", requireAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = Item.find()
    query.exec().then(items => {
      const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => item.userId === req.user.userId);
      res.send(items);
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: it returns an empty array

Comment: Maybe you need an empty object in the parameter like `Item.find({})`.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you are trying to use the array methods on other data structures.

This piece of code returns an error `.filter is not a function`:

```js
const myList = await getList().filter(item => item.myKey > 10);
```

**Solution**:

```js
const data = await getList();
const myList = data.filter(item => item.myKey > 10);
```